# What's this inside the RD-0120?

Tags: engines, injector

There is a decent shot of the RD-0120's inside in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J29xBozuvFk&t=1703s):

[image]

I guess it's something covering the injector plate or even the combustion chamber since the SSME's injector looks very differently:

[image]

Also, is it likely that this particular engine has been test fired before?

Comment: I also found this related document about the RD-0120 here: http://lpre.de/resources/articles/AIAA-1995-2540.pdf

Comment: Related throat plug question:https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48490/6944

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a nozzle plug which covers the combustion chamber. A closer look at the shot does not show any holes in the object so it cannot be the injector plate. In the photo you can't see the converging part of the engine so it can't cover the injector plate.

The Energia that is in the video was a structural boilerplate with real engines, according to [Orbiter Forum:](https://www.orbiter-forum.com/threads/energia-m-discovered-in-baikonur-vab.33339/)

> Just read the link - it's not the real thing, but a dynamic test mock-up. Essentially a boilerplate rocket with real engines - they were in the middle of testing the design when the program folded.

[image: Energia mockup shown in video]

They never fired these engines as it was only a *structural* mockup and wasn't designed to be flown, kind of like SA-500D which was only structural and never was used for firing engines. Hopefully this clarifies things.