# Are nozzle plugs taken out before launch or are they ejected upon ignition?

Tags: launch, engines, nozzle

Inspired by [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/59182/30164). For most orbital launch vehicles, do their engines have nozzle plugs installed and what happen to them at launch? Are they manually removed during the prelaunch/rollout or are they ejected during engine ignition?

Comment: For which rocket?

Comment: @GdD This was a somewhat hasty question, I've edited it to clarify things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, nozzle plugs like those depicted in the linked question, as well as other assorted engine protection setups like [these nozzle FOD covers](https://www.americaspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/maf_20200108_artemis_roll_out_dn-5673_0-758x426.jpg) are almost always removed prior to flight, during the final assembly and preparation prior to launch. Many, such as [turbopump inlet covers](https://www.rrauction.com/auctions/lot-detail/345652306349113-rocketdyne-j-2-rocket-engine-main-fuel-and-lox-valve-closures-covers/?cat=359) absolutely must be removed, as they otherwise interfere with integration of the engine.

These parts are used to prevent foreign object damage (FOD) or debris ingress, and in particular the above nozzle plug is almost certainly to help keep debris away from and out of the sensitive injector assembly. It could also be that the interior of the engine plumbing is "purged" with inert gas to prevent oxidation or corrosion prior to use or during shipping, but the procedures, if any, vary engine-to-engine.

It would generally be a bad idea to fire an engine with one of these plugs in place. Aside from the most flimsy of covers (paper, mylar, etc.) which will safely rupture, firing a large metal plug out of the nozzle is likely to damage it in the process, particularly if it tumbles and strikes the inner surface. Having the nozzle plugged at initial startup also runs the risk of an overpressure event the engine thrust chamber structure may not be designed to account for.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Of course - the "almost" wording was more intended to cover all the bases in specialized (or obscure) use cases. I know there was a question floating around awhile back about the [torn-out covers on the Shuttle RCS pods](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33828/what-are-these-membranes-at-the-aft-end-of-the-shuttle-that-get-torn-off-during).

Comment: Thanks for the link to an additional RCS covers question! Adding it.

Answer (score 10):

Certainly all the big shuttle engines: OMS, SSME  and SRB covers and plugs were, ahem, "removed before flight".

However some of the shuttle Reaction Control System engines had covers applied to them that blew off at launch. This was intended to keep rain from collecting in the nozzles.

For details see

- [Did any of the Space Shuttle RCS covers ever stay on?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44089/did-any-of-the-space-shuttle-rcs-covers-ever-stay-on/44095#44095)
- [What are these membranes at the aft end of the Shuttle that get torn off during lift off?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33828/what-are-these-membranes-at-the-aft-end-of-the-shuttle-that-get-torn-off-during)

Some solid rocket strapons used on expendable boosters have nozzle closures that are still affixed at liftoff (emphasis mine)

> The air-start (altitude-ignited) GEM 40 motor
> configuration has a lengthened nozzle exit cone with higher
> expansion ratio, **exit-plane-mounted nozzle closure system that
> is ejected at air-start motor ignitio**n, and a different external
> insulation scheme.

Source:[Northrop Grumman Propulsion Products Catalog](https://www.northropgrumman.com/wp-content/uploads/NG-Propulsion-Products-Catalog.pdf)

[image]

Source: [tweet](https://twitter.com/SpacesFuture/status/1252596612330696704/photo/1) by Tory Bruno